# help with glob pattern

Tags: php, glob

It would be nice if someone could give me a regexp pattern for glob for getting below filenames:

```
1.jpg // this file
1_thumb.jpg
2.png // this file
2_thumb.png
etc...
```

returning the files without "_thumb". I have this pattern:

```
$numericalFiles = glob("$this->path/*_thumb.*");
```

and that give me all with "_thumb."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`glob()` isn't the greatest at handling situations where you have complex requirements for file matching, as you've clearly noticed.  I'd recommend using PHP's SPL library and taking advantage of the [DirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) class.

```
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator("/dir/path");
foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    if ($file->isFile() && preg_match("/^[0-9]+\./i",$file->getFilename())) {
        echo $file->getFilename();
    }
}
```

You can modify your criteria cleanly during the iteration (also, it's easy to modify the iterator if you ever needed [recursive directory iteration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)).

Comment: But it *is* possible that `glob()` could be handled by the libc, so starting with it means that you'll iterate through fewer results in the much slower PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Glob patterns and regular expressions are different. But PHP's glob implementation does not implement the pattern negation required for matching just those files. You will need to use a larger positive pattern such as `[0-9]*.jpg` and then filter the results afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (glob('[0-9]*') as $filename) {
    if (strpos("$filename","_thumb") === FALSE){
        echo "$filename \n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Further to [zombat's use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084325/help-with-glob-regexp/2084498#2084498) of the DirectoryIterator, it might also make sense to construct your own specialized filter class to make life easier (see the difference with the `foreach` loops) and more reusable.

```
class DirectoryFilterThumbs extends FilterIterator {
    public function __construct($path) {
        parent::__construct(new DirectoryIterator($path));
    }
    public function accept() {
        // Use regex or whatever you like here
        return ($this->isFile() && strpos($this->getFilename(), "_thumb.") === FALSE);
    }
}

$files = new DirectoryFilterThumbs("/dir/path");
foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo $file->getFilename() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Of course, if there is no need to do this in multiple places then the plain DirectoryIterator/condition combo given by zombat is perfectly suitable.